# Método Gauss-Seidel en C++

Tags: c++, algoritmos, dev-c++

Tengo un problema, estoy haciendo un programa que haga el método matemático Gauss-Seidel y la idea principal es que a partir de el resultado de una ecuación puedas resolver las `x` incógnitas en las demás ecuaciones, aquí dejo mi programa:

```
//Gauss Seidel

include < iostream >
  include < conio.h >
  include < stdlib.h >

  using namespace std;

int main() {
  float matriz[100][100];
  float preoperaciones[100][100];
  float operaciones[100][100];
  float respuestas[100][100];
  float resultado;
  int filasM, columnasM, n;
  float porcentajeMinimo = 0;
  char ans;

  //Preguntando por dimensiones
  while (filasM != columnasM || (filasM <= 0 && columnasM <= 0) || (filasM > 100 && columnasM > 100)) {
    cout << "Cuantas columnas quieres en tu matriz?" << endl;
    cin >> columnasM;
    cout << "Cuantas filas quieres en tu matriz?" << endl;
    cin >> filasM;
    if ((filasM <= 0 || columnasM <= 0) || (filasM > 100 || columnasM > 100)) {
      cout << "Las dimensiones de la matriz son " << filasM << "x" << columnasM << endl;
      cout << "Debe de introducir numeros mayores a 0 y menores a 99" << endl << "Presiona una tecla para continuar" << endl;
      getch();
      system("CLS");
    } else {
      cout << "Presiona una tecla para continuar" << endl;
      getch();
      system("CLS");
      if (filasM != columnasM) {
        cout << "Las dimensiones de la matriz son " << filasM << "x" << columnasM << endl;
        cout << "Debe de ser una matriz rectangular!" << endl << "Presiona una tecla para continuar" << endl;
        getch();
        system("CLS");
      } else {
        cout << "Las dimensiones de la matriz son " << filasM << "x" << columnasM << endl;
        cout << "Las filas y columnas son Iguales" << endl;
        cout << "Presiona una tecla para continuar" << endl;
        getch();
        system("CLS");
      }
    }

  }

  //Recogiendo los valores de la matriz
  cout << "Las dimensiones de la matriz son " << filasM << "x" << columnasM << endl;
  for (int i1 = 0; i1 < filasM; i1++) {
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < columnasM; i2++) {
      cout << "Introduce un numero en la posicion " << i1 + 1 << "," << i2 + 1 << ":" << endl;
      cin >> matriz[i1][i2];
      if (i1 != i2) {
        preoperaciones[i1][i2 + 1] = matriz[i1][i2];
      }
    }
  }

  cout << "Introduce los resultados de cada ecuacion" << endl;
  columnasM = columnasM + 1;
  for (int i1 = 0; i1 < filasM; i1++) {
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < columnasM; i2++) {
      if (i2 == columnasM - 1) {
        cout << "=";
        cin >> matriz[i1][i2];
      } else {
        if (matriz[i1][i2] >= 0) {
          cout << " " << "+" << matriz[i1][i2] << "x" << i2 + 1 << " ";
        } else {
          cout << " " << matriz[i1][i2] << "x" << i2 + 1 << " ";
        }
      }

    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  //Mostrando los valores de la matriz como ecuacion
  cout << "Nuestra ecuacion queda:" << endl;
  for (int i1 = 0; i1 < filasM; i1++) {
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < columnasM; i2++) {
      if (i2 == columnasM - 1) {
        cout << "=";
        cout << " " << matriz[i1][i2] << " ";
        preoperaciones[i1][0] = matriz[i1][i2];
      } else {
        if (matriz[i1][i2] >= 0) {
          cout << " " << "+" << matriz[i1][i2] << "x" << i2 + 1 << " ";
        } else {
          cout << " " << matriz[i1][i2] << "x" << i2 + 1 << " ";
        }
      }
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  int identidad[100];
  float suma[100];
  cout << "Tomaremos la matriz identidad de nuestra matriz recien creada" << endl;
  for (int i1 = 0; i1 < filasM; i1++) {
    suma[i1] = 0;
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < columnasM - 1; i2++) {
      if (i1 == i2) {
        cout << "Posicion " << i1 + 1 << "," << i2 + 1 << ": ";
        cout << matriz[i1][i2];
        preoperaciones[i1][columnasM] = matriz[i1][i2];
        cout << endl;
        //  cout<<preoperaciones[i1][0]<<"\t";
        //  cout<<preoperaciones[i1][columnasM]<<endl;
      } else {
        if (i1 != i2) {
          suma[i1] += matriz[i1][i2];
        }
      }

    }
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < columnasM - 1; i2++) {
      if (i1 == i2) {
        if (suma[i2] > matriz[i1][i2]) { // si los 3 son 1 entonces la matriz es diagonalmente dominante
          identidad[i1] = 0;
          //    cout<<endl<<"Identidad "<<identidad[i1];
        } else {
          if (suma[i2] <= matriz[i1][i2]) {
            identidad[i1] = 1;
            //  cout<<endl<<"Identidad "<<identidad[i1];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  int dominante = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < filasM; i++) {
    if (identidad[i] == 1) {
      dominante = dominante + 1;
    }
  }

  if (dominante >= filasM) {
    cout << endl << "La matriz es diagonalmente dominante" << endl;
  } else {
    if (dominante < filasM) {
      cout << endl << "La matriz no es diagonalmente dominante" << endl;
    }
  }

  getch();
  system("CLS"); //Borramos la pantalla actual

  //Aqui se introduce el error minimo que debe de haber 
  do {
    cout << "Quieres ingresar un porcentaje?(S/N)" << endl;
    cin >> ans;
    if ((ans == 'S') || (ans == 's')) {
      do {
        cout << "Ingresa un porcentaje:" << endl;
        cin >> porcentajeMinimo;
        if (porcentajeMinimo < 0) {
          cout << "Ingresa un porcentaje valido" << endl;
          cout << "Presiona una tecla para continuar" << endl;
          getch();
          system("CLS");
        }
      } while (porcentajeMinimo < 0);
    } else {
      if ((ans == 'N') || (ans == 'n')) {
        cout << "No hay porcentaje" << endl;
      }
      if ((ans != 's') && (ans != 's') && (ans != 'N') && (ans != 'n')) {
        cout << "Introduce una letra valida" << endl;
        getch();
        system("CLS");
      }
    }
  } while ((ans != 's') && (ans != 's') && (ans != 'N') && (ans != 'n'));

  cout << "Presiona una tecla para continuar" << endl;
  getch();
  system("CLS");

  //operaciones a mostrar en pantalla
  cout << "Operaciones a realizar" << endl;
  for (int i1 = 0; i1 < filasM; i1++) {
    n = i1;
    cout << "( ";
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 <= columnasM; i2++) {
      if ((i2 != 0) && (i2 != columnasM)) {
        if ((i1 == n) && (i2 == n + 1)) {
          //Cuando la fila vale n y la columna vale n+1 no imprimira nada
        } else {
          if (preoperaciones[i1][i2] >= 0) {
            cout << "-" << preoperaciones[i1][i2] << "x" << i2 << " ";
            operaciones[i1][i2] = preoperaciones[i1][i2];
          } else {
            cout << "+" << (-1 * preoperaciones[i1][i2]) << "x" << i2 << " ";
            operaciones[i1][i2] = preoperaciones[i1][i2];
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (i2 == columnasM) {
          cout << ") / " << preoperaciones[i1][i2];
          operaciones[i1][i2] = preoperaciones[i1][i2];
        } else {
          cout << preoperaciones[i1][i2] << " ";
          operaciones[i1][i2] = preoperaciones[i1][i2];
        }
      }
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  //Realizamos las operaciones dependiendo de los valores de las variables
  int apagar = 2;
  int i = 0, valorInicial = 0;
  float respuestasX[100][100];
  float errorAprox = porcentajeMinimo + 1, actual, anterior;
  int pos1, pos2;

  if ((ans == 'n') || (ans == 'N')) {
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 2; i1++) {
      cout << "Iteracion " << i1 + 1 << ": " << endl;
      for (int i2 = 0; i2 < filasM; i2++) {
        n = i2;
        for (int i3 = 0; i3 <= columnasM; i3++) {
          if ((i2 == n) && (i3 == n + 1)) {
            //Ignorando el vacio
          }
          if (i3 == 0) {
            respuestasX[i1][i3] = respuestasX[i1][i3] + (operaciones[i2][i3]);
          } else {
            if (i3 == columnasM) {
              respuestasX[i1][i3] = respuestasX[i1][i3] / operaciones[i2][i3];
              pos1 = i2;
              pos2 = i3;
            } else {
              if (i3 != i2) {
                if ((i1 == 0) && (i2 == 0)) {
                  respuestasX[i1][i3] = respuestasX[i1][i3] + (operaciones[i2][i3] * valorInicial);
                }
                if (i1 >= 1) {
                  if (i2 >= 0) {
                    respuestasX[i1][i3] = respuestasX[i1][i3] + (operaciones[i2][i3] * respuestasX[pos1][pos2]);
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }

        }
        cout << "Resultado x" << i2 + 1 << ": " << respuestasX[i1][i2] << endl;

      }
      cout << endl;
    }
  }

  if ((ans == 's') || (ans == 'S')) {
    cout << "El error aproximado sera menor a " << porcentajeMinimo << "%" << endl;
    do {
      for (int i1 = 0; i1 < filasM; i1++) {
        n = i1;
        resultado = 0;
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 <= columnasM; i2++) {
          if ((i1 == n) && (i2 == n + 1)) {
            //Ignorando el vacio
          }
          if (i2 == 0) {
            resultado = resultado + (operaciones[i1][i2]);
          } else {
            if (i2 == columnasM) {
              resultado = resultado / operaciones[i1][i2];
              pos1 = i1;
              pos2 = i2;
            } else {
              if (i2 >= 1) {
                if (i1 <= 0) {
                  resultado = resultado + (operaciones[i1][i2] * valorInicial);
                } else {
                  if (i1 > 0) {
                    resultado = resultado + (operaciones[i1][i2] * respuestasX[pos1][pos2]);

                    /*  cout<<"i1: "<<i1<<endl;
                        cout<<"i2: "<<i2<<endl;*/
                  }
                }
              }

            }
          }
        }
        respuestas[i][i1] = resultado;
        cout << respuestas[i][i1] << endl;
      }
      if (i > 0) {
        cout << endl << "Iteracion " << i + 1 << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < columnasM; j++) {
          anterior = respuestas[i - 1][j];
          actual = respuestas[i][j];
          errorAprox = ((actual - anterior) / actual) * 100;
          cout << endl << "Respuesta Actual: " << actual << endl;
          cout << endl << "Respuesta anterior: " << anterior << endl;
          cout << endl << "Error Aproximado actual: " << errorAprox << endl;
        }
      } else {
        cout << endl << "Iteracion " << i + 1;
        cout << endl << "~" << endl;
      }
      i++;
    } while (errorAprox > porcentajeMinimo);
  }

  //Aqui termina la ejecucion del programa
  cout << "Hasta aqui llega la ejecucion del programa";
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*Tengo un problema*" y sin embargo no dices cuál es.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Revisa [help] y [ask]. En particular, explica cuál es el problema; eso incluye describir qué datos procesas, qué resultado esperas y qué resultado obtienes. También incluye delimitar el alcance del problema (¿es un problema de qué no lee los datos correctamente? ¿los cálculos no dan el resultado correcto? etc.). El depurador y `cout` son tus amigos...